# Firefox option to restore session on startup is greyed out

Tags: 12.04, firefox, desktop-environments

Firefox's `Edit->Preferences->General->When Firefox Starts` menu has several options, but the last one, "Show Windows and tabs from last time" is greyed out and unavailable.  Anyone know why this would be and how to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your history option disabled, or you have any kind of setting that deletes all information every time you close firefox? Because the program won't be able to restore the tabs if it's  not keeping info about them. These options are on the privacy section, check it out. Good luck!

Comment: Nailed it, thanks.  Firefox was set by default to use to custom history settings, but changing it to fully enabled fixed everything.  Muchos gracias!

Comment: Glad it helped. Just be carefull with those settings, I assume that's your personal PC and not a public or working place one, so you won't have privacy problems keeping the data after using it.